# Swift syntax error?

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

Why am I getting an `[AnyObject]! is not convertible to 'Void'` error here? Am I just not seeing some little syntax error or something??

```
    var popClosure = {()->Void in presentingController!.popToViewController(dest!, animated: false)}
```

It is only getting called once inside this method:

```
src!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: popClosure)
```

Here's the full code:

```
class ColorfulUnwindSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
{
private let ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.5

override func perform()
{
    var dest = self.destinationViewController as? UIViewController
    var src = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController

    if src && dest
    {
        dest!.view.frame = CGRectMake(-dest!.view.frame.size.width, 0, dest!.view.frame.size.width, dest!.view.frame.size.height)

        var srcIsModal = false

        var presentingController = src!.navigationController as? ColorfulNavigationController

        if src!.presentingViewController as? ColorfulNavigationController
        {
            srcIsModal = true
            presentingController = src!.presentingViewController as? ColorfulNavigationController
        }

        if presentingController
        {
            if srcIsModal
            {
                var popClosure : ()->Void = {()->Void in presentingController!.popToViewController(dest!, animated: false)}

                src!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: popClosure)
            }
            else
            {
                src!.view.layer.addSublayer(dest!.view.layer)

                UIView.animateWithDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION,
                    animations:
                    {()->Void in
                        src!.view.frame = CGRectMake(dest!.view.frame.size.width, 0, src!.view.frame.size.width, src!.view.frame.size.height)
                    },
                    completion:
                    {(finished:Bool)->Void in
                        if finished
                        {
                            presentingController!.popToViewController(dest!, animated: false)
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run that code inside the curly braces every time you call ``popClosure``?

Comment: can you please describe what you are trying to do with this code. It does not make any sense.

Comment: Can you post more of the code.  It's not clear what context this code is in, or how you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like since you only have one method call in your closure it's trying to store that method in popClosure.

```
 func popToViewController(viewController: UIViewController!, animated: Bool) -> [AnyObject]!
```

Because that one method returns `[AnyObject]!`, popClosure returns `[AnyObject]!` which doesn't match up with its declared type `() -> Void`.

You can workaround this by just adding another line to your closure. It doesn't have to do anything. As rickster suggested, in this example I simply add a return to the closure.

```
var popClosure: () -> Void = { () -> Void in
    presentingController!.popToViewController(dest!, animated: false)
    return
}
```

The compiler then seems to understand you are defining a closure in which that method is called.

Comment: If you're going to put a dummy line at the end of a closure to convince the compiler it has no return value, it's probably clearer to make that line be `return`.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll add that. You could also use a literal.

Comment: Anyone else tempted to raise a bug report for this one? It may be "works as intended", but it's probably going to confuse a lot of people. I don't really see anything wrong with quietly throwing away an implicitly-generated return on a Void-returning function.

Comment: @Matt: It's working exactly as documented, and it is useful. Single-expression closures automatically return that expression's value. It allows you to write things like `foo.map { $0.bar }` concisely. It's only confusing when you make a single-expression closure with an expression that returns a value and ignore the return value. That isn't amazingly common, and I don't see anything wrong with having to indicate that you meant to ignore a return value.

Comment: @Chuck Yeah, that's what I meant by "implicitly-generated return". I suppose it just feels to me a bit like two parts of the language that are each meant to help you are clashing a little here, and it feels a little mis-matching to me. I've not raised a bug on it though, as I think you're right that it probably won't do much harm; it's just something else to get used to.